# Can Rebol 3 be embedded as Scripting Language for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, rebol

It is said here:
http://fourdman.blogspot.com/2009/06/cocolua-lua-objective-c.html
Lua is a very lightweight (but powerful) language which depends on C only. You don't need to pull many N-megabyte frameworks and libraries. Lua was created as an embeddable language: you add its interpreter's source code to your project and use is programmatically. Apart of many other things that means that you can use Lua even on the iPhone and no one will ever notice that.

As far as I understand new Rebol 3 core version (rebol view can't be used but cocoa gui framework) will have the capability to be an embedded scripting engine. Does this mean that it could be embedded like LUA in Corona SDK as a scripting language for the iPhone or maybe also Android ?

Rebol core is much less than 1 mo Lua I don't know I'm just downloading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple allows embedded scripting languages in iOS apps (there are even Basic interpreters in the App store), but does not allow any capability for an app to download new code or scripts which that scripting language can run.  All scripts have to be built-in to the submitted app.

This was a change to their developer agreement about late-Q3 2010.

When porting a scripting language, you also have to make sure the language's run time does not reach outside the iOS process, file directory, and IO sandbox, but only uses documented Cocoa Touch APIs for IO and UI (e.g. no stdin, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link with more thorough tec doc ?